# JPA Select from (Select)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Is there some way to represent this kind of SQL with JPA or Hibernate Crtiteria API? Or shall I execute it as native?

SELECT A.X FROM (SELECT X, E.id FROM Employee E) as A WHERE A.id = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://queryhql-subqueries):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

So yes, such a query can only be done using native SQL.